# Get data from json file in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, service, get, subscribe

I have a json file and I'm trying to put this information in my project with a service in Angular 2. Here is my code:

**That is my service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RecordsService {

data: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getRecords(id) {
 return this.http.get('../assets/data/03_data.json')
      .map(data => {
        this.data = data;
      }, err => {
        if (err) {
          return err.json();
        }
      });
  }

}
```

**That is the component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RecordsService } from '../shared/services/records.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css'],
  providers: [RecordsService]
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private recService: RecordsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getRecords(id) {
    this.recService.getRecords(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

}
```

Can someone help me what I did wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `getRecords()` anywhere so it will not be fired at all. We found out that the `id` wasn't supposed to be a parameter in `getRecords()` at all. So call the method in `OnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getRecords();
}
```

also you need to return the actual json from the response, i.e `.json()` so do:

```
.map(data => {
   this.data = data.json();
   return data.json();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something from your `map` statement:

```
.map(data => {
        this.data = data;
        return data;
      }
```

Comment: I haven't nothing in the console again. :(

Comment: probably should be `data.json()` ;)

Comment: @vesselinivanov when you check your network tab in developer tools, do you see the response?

Comment: @echonax nope I didn't see a response for my service.

Comment: @AJT_82 I called getRecord() in my component:   this.recService.getRecords(id)

Comment: @vesselinivanov AAH, nevermind, my brain is not functioning properly. Carry on :D

Comment: @vesselinivanov, where **are** you calling this method? I mean the component method.

Comment: I thinks it's done. Now in the console i have Array(100) and all objects.I set getRecords in ngOnInit and wrote        
 this.data = data.json();
 return data.json();

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks Bro, I really appreciate it. You have one vodka Finlandia from me. ;)

Comment: @vesselinivanov, haha :D So my answer was basically correct then, I thought you had a click event or something to call the component method. So how do you get the `id` in the component method `getRecords(id)` if you call it from `OnInit`? Just out of curiousity :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I deleted id from the method, I think I dont need it. I'm basic with Angular 2, so I'm not sure what I do. lol :D